# How to Defend Against Port Scan Attacks

Tags: ports, network-scanners

I was told that Hackers scan for open ports in random IPs and if they are open they hack the computer.

What open ports can be hacked? How do I close the ports?

Comment: if you are running on very old windows system like xp sp2 there is a chance if you have opened port 465 (I think SMB) they can use exploit to gain full access over your system, but as MechMK1 and schroeder said, there is no need to worry.

Answer (score 1):

## What is an "open port"?

An "open port" is actually a bit misleading. People tend to think of their computer as a solid wall, and of an "open port" to be akin to a hole in the wall.

What an open port actually is is an application on your computer listening to network traffic. So for example, if you run a game server on your computer (e.g. Minecraft, Unreal Tournament, etc...), the application "opens" a port, so that others can connect to that application.

## Are open ports dangerous?

Not necessarily. It depends on the application, which is listening to the network traffic. Sometimes, these applications can have bugs, that allow an attacker to do malicious things, such as reading files from your computer, run their own malicious programs, etc.

Usually, you will be fine if you see an open port and recognize the application behind it.

## Can hackers open ports?

Usually not, and there is no need for them. If a hacker is in the position to launch any program on your computer, they are already *in* your system. Think of it like a thief, who opens a window from inside the house, so he can come into the house. It doesn't make sense.

That said, during some attacks, hackers may have limited capabilities, and in order to extend their capabilities, they run a program that opens a port and allows the attacker to connect in an easier way.

Answer (score 0):

Ports are not the issue. It's the service running on those ports. Services like a web server, an email server, a game server, or whatever.

Services should only be open to the Internet if they are supposed to be public like that, so there are firewalls that you can use to block those ports from going to certain places but allow access to other places, like the Internet.

Otherwise, you either want to stop that service from running or configure it to stop having access to the network.